# Sequelize Typescript, create with assocations hasMany and belongsTo

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to be able to create an assocation using a create field, but for some reason its not working

index.ts

```
  const user = await User.create({name: 'username', posts: []})
  const post = await Post.create({table: 'title of a post', user: user, userId: 1}, {include: User})
```

database.ts

```
import { InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes } from 'sequelize'
import { Table, Column, ForeignKey, BelongsTo, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript'

    @Table
    export class Post extends Model<InferAttributes<Post>, InferCreationAttributes<Post>>  {
    
        @Column
        table: string
    
        @ForeignKey(() => User)
        @Column
        userId: number
      
        @BelongsTo(() => User)
        user: User
    }
    
    @Table
    export class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User>, InferCreationAttributes<User>>  {
    
        @Column
        name: string
    
        @HasMany(() => Post)
        posts: Post[]
    }
```

Getting the error
`[1]     __metadata("design:type", User) [1]                               ^ [1] [1] ReferenceError: Cannot access 'User' before initialization`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to import/require your model. Something like this

import User from "PATH/TO/YOUR_MODEL"

Comment: All the models are in the same file

Comment: Post entire code that you have in your file

Comment: I changed it, but the only other stuff I think I had was import { InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes } from 'sequelize'
import { Table, Column, ForeignKey, BelongsTo, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript'

Comment: There seemed to be a problem with having the classes all in one file and also with the extending classes